# Strip Linked Product and dSYM

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to strip symbols to make my app size smaller. The following is my setting.

```
Generate Debug Symbols -> YES
Debug Information Format -> DWARF with dSYM File
Deployment Postprocessing ->YES
Strip Linked Product -> YES
Strip Style -> All symbols
```

My Question is that can I still symbolicate the crash log with dSYM file?

Comment: Don't understand your question. Can you please write what you want to do clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need your dSYM file for that and you have that after your build.